# How to get records by joining id in one table with id in multiple columns in another table in bigquery for huge tables?

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I have two tables emp and prj. Columns and data types of tables are as follows Emp has EmpNo(INT), EmpITPrj(STR), EmpFinPrj(STR), EmpHRPrj(STR), EmpIntPrj(STR), EmpDate(STR) and prj has PrjID(STR), PrjStartDate(STR), PrjEndDate(STR). The goal is to display all records that match the condition prj.PrjID is in one of the columns of emp.EmpITPrj, emp.EmpFinPrj, emp.EmpHRPrj or emp.EmpIntPrj AND emp.Date falls on or between the prj.PrjStartDate, prj.PrjEndDate.

But also the solution should be feasible for actual number of rows/columns. 
emp - 2M rows and 1.8k columns and prj - 10k rows and 100 columns.

```
EmpNo   EmpITPrj    EmpFinPrj   EmpHRPrj    EmpIntPrj   Date
1         IT101       null        null         null     2019-09-01
2         null        Fin101      null         null     2001-06-05
3         null        Fin102      null         null     2005-11-25
4         null        null        null         Int501   2010-10-15
5         null        null        null         Int105   2019-01-10
6         null        null        null         Int444   2015-12-03
7         null        null        HR110        null     2012-08-19
8         IT101       null        null         null     2011-04-24
9         null        null        HR105        null     2005-02-09
10        IT102       null        null         null     2006-07-11



PrjID   PrjStartDate    PrjEndDate
Fin102  10/14/2005      12/14/2005
IT102   07/11/2006      10/30/2006
IT110   11/15/2010      01/31/2011
Int101  01/01/2015      03/31/2015
HR110   05/19/2012      08/19/2012
Int444  01/01/2015      03/01/2015

End Result:
EmpNo   EmpITPrj    EmpFinPrj   EmpHRPrj    EmpIntPrj   EmpDate     PrjID   PrjStartDate    PrjEndDate
3       null        Fin102      null        null        2005-11-25  Fin102  10/14/2005      12/14/2005
10      IT102       null        null        null        2006-07-11  IT102   07/11/2006      10/30/2006
7       null        null        HR110       null        2012-08-19  HR110   05/19/2012      08/19/2012
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for but below at least eliminates direct referencing all fields from emp table. if you have multiple fields to involve in prj table - you can extend this solution by applying similar logic

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `bigquery-project-123.emp` AS t1
JOIN `bigquery-project-123.prj` t2 
ON CONCAT('"', t2.PrjID, '"') IN UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(FORMAT('%T', t1), r'^\(|\)$', ''), ', '))
AND SAFE.PARSE_DATE("%Y-%m-%d", t1.EmpDate) BETWEEN 
SAFE.PARSE_DATE("%m/%d/%Y",t2.PrjStartDate) AND SAFE.PARSE_DATE("%m/%d/%Y",t2.PrjEndDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

This query will provide the result that you are looking for:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  `BQ_TABLE_emp` AS emp
JOIN 
  `BQ_TABLE_prj` AS prj
ON
  prj.PrjID IN (emp.EmpITPrj, emp.EmpFinPrj, emp.EmpHRPrj, emp.EmpIntPrj) AND
  emp.Date BETWEEN prj.PrjStartDate AND prj.PrjEndDate;
```

In order to improve the performance of this job, I suggest to specify explicitly the content of the JOIN condition as follows:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  `BQ_TABLE_emp` AS emp
JOIN 
  `BQ_TABLE_prj` AS prj
ON
  (prj.PrjID = emp.EmpITPrj OR prj.PrjID = emp.EmpFinPrj OR prj.PrjID = emp.EmpHRPrj OR prj.PrjID = emp.EmpIntPrj) AND
  (emp.Date >= prj.PrjStartDate AND emp.Date <= prj.PrjEndDate);
```

I have tested the above solutions in BigQuery for the case of 2M rows and 1.8K in the tables `emp` and `prj` respectively and both are feasible. Keep in mind that, due to the complicated JOIN condition, this type of statements usually lead to a massive manipulation of data that can exhaust the available resources.

Comment: Thank you @Juan Fernandez Afonso.